# Convert SVG to transparent PNG with antialiasing, using ImageMagick

Tags: svg, imagemagick, png, inkscape

I want to convert SVG images to PNG files with transparent background and anti-aliased edges (using semi-transparent pixels). Unfortunately I can't get ImageMagick to do the anti-aliasing, the edges always look terrible. Here's what I tried:

```
convert +antialias -background transparent  in.svg -resize 25x25 out.png
```

Any ideas or a different command line tool I could use?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Inkscape will do this:

```
inkscape \
    --export-png=out.png --export-dpi=200 \
    --export-background-opacity=0 --without-gui in.svg
```

### Update

The terminology has [changed](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Command_Line): all the export params suppress gui, and the output parameter is now simply based on the file type. For example, a type of `png` will cause a file in `/path/to/picture.svg` to be exported as `/path/to/picture.png` (caution: this overwrites output).

```
inkscape \
    --export-type=png --export-dpi=200 \
    --export-background-opacity=0 picture.svg
```

Note cited wiki has quotes on `--export-type=png`, which is incorrect.

Also if don't have Inkscape command line, MacOS can access via bash directly:

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape
```

Comment: The first solution I've found that keeps the color palette of some SVGs, e.g. the logo of Apache NiFi (https://nifi.apache.org/assets/images/apache-nifi-logo.svg).

Comment: Imagemagick now will use Inkscape if it is installed on the system. You have the choice of: Inkscape (if on the system), RSVG delegate (must be installed with Imagemagick, or the Imagemagick internal MSVG/XML.

Comment: The "supply `-background none` before the SVG filename" answer is much better because it actually uses ImageMagick, the tool asked about…: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18579465/1901658

Comment: @FredrickBrennan: my general view is that readers (and question authors) will use the tool that gives them the best results. If an OP is made that asks how to knock in a nail with a screwdriver, sometimes an answer that recommends a hammer anyway is best, even if it is "not what they asked for".

Comment: (Nice to hear there's more than one way to do it though ).

Comment: Well, since user said they needed command line tool, I assume servers are involved, and ImageMagick is easier is much easier to run on servers, not requiring a little of Xorg dependencies. But yes, OK.

Answer (score 134):

Instead of `-background transparent`, use `-background none`.

```
convert -background none in.svg out.png
```

**NOTE:** The order of the arguments is important.

Comment: At least at this time (6.8.6), it works with _transparent_ too.

Comment: Both 'none' and 'transparent' create opaque white background for me. Not transparent. I'm using 6.8.8-3 on Mac

Comment: `-background none` worked for me, ImageMagick 6.8.6-6 on a mac

Comment: @petrsyn although the command will accept the input image path as the first argument (e.g. `convert in.svg -background none out.png`, I found that this ordering will fail to make the background transparent; it resulted in an opaque white background! Make sure that `in.svg` and `out.png` are the *final two arguments* in the command.

Comment: This removed the color palette of a SVG I tried to convert (https://nifi.apache.org/assets/images/apache-nifi-logo.svg).

Comment: `-background none` is indeed correct as per the image magic [color names documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php): *"There is also a color called 'none' that is fully transparent. This color is shorthand for `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)`."*

Comment: this works! if it doesn't you probably have a background *inside* of your SVG that you're unaware of! That took me a while to find out lol...

Comment: If it isn't working for your SVG, check whether the SVG is using `style` attributes (like `style="fill:#ff0000;stroke:#000"`) and try changing them to attributes: `fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000"`

Answer (score 19):

Actually, reading imagemagick documentation:

> -antialias
>
> Enable/Disable of the rendering of anti-aliasing pixels when drawing fonts and lines.
>   By default, objects (e.g. text, lines, polygons, etc.) are antialiased when drawn. Use 
>   +antialias to disable the addition of antialiasing edge pixels. This will then reduce the
>   number of colors added to an image to just the colors being directly drawn. That is, no 
>   mixed >colors are added when drawing such objects.

the **+antialias** will indeed disable antialiasing.

Comment: They got it backwards :|

Answer (score 12):

The way I learned how to do this was from the methodology found here: [How to convert a .eps file to a high quality 1024x1024 .jpg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583821/how-to-convert-a-eps-file-to-a-high-quality-1024x1024-jpg)

It is the same idea as @halfer's solution with `inkscape`--to jack up the DPI first--but you can accomplish the same thing in just `imagemagick` using the `-density` option.

```
convert -density 200 in.svg -resize 25x25 -transparent white out.png
```

Comment: This solution, while it may work for many SVG files, is inferior to the `-background none` solution, because white is a valid fill/stroke color that may present in many SVG's, and this turns all white pixels transparent, even those defined as being white fills/strokes.

Answer (score 5):

Adding the `-transparent white` option **solves the problem particularly** in my case because background isn't removed completely (unfortunately light shadow is present). So I'm using IMHO more clearer **solution that fully removes background** with ImageMagic:

`convert -channel rgba -background "rgba(0,0,0,0)" in.svg out.png`

It sets a fully transparent black color as the background through the RGBA channel.

Comment: This is the relevant documentation for the `-transparent` option: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#transparent

Comment: After fiddling with it for a while, this was **the only** way to get it to work - much appreciated!

Comment: `-background none` works just as well in recent IM releases, and avoids needing to supply `-channel rgba` if the target is PNG

Answer (score 5):

For me that works for svg to png:

```sh
convert ${src} \
    -transparent white \
    -background none \
    -resize 345x345 \
    res/drawable-xxxhdpi/${dest}
```

Comment: There is no reason to supply _both_ `-transparent white` and `-background none`, and this will negatively effect files with elements of the foreground that are _supposed_ to be white. Only supply `-background none`.

Answer (score 0):

I get better, already nicely antialiased results if I replace `-resize` with `-scale`. Then, the `antialias` flag isn't even necessary.

Answer (score -1):

I add a rect as background. 
The embed CSS hide the background.
Then I catch its color for setting the transparent attribute of ImageMagick.

---

SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'>
<svg 
    version="1.1" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="500px" height="500px"
    viewBox="0 0 500 500" 
    enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" 
    >
<defs>
    <style>
        #background { display: none; }
    </style>
</defs>
<rect id="background" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" fill="#e8e437"/>
<!-- beginning of the sketch -->
<g fill="#000" text-anchor="middle"font-size="112">
    <text y="350" x="192">OK</text>
</g>
<!-- end of the sketch -->
</svg>
```

---

bash script

```
#!/bin/bash


BASE_DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null && pwd )
SVG_DIR="$BASE_DIR/import"
PNG_DIR="$BASE_DIR/export"

for f in `ls $SVG_DIR/*.svg`
do
    g="$PNG_DIR/$(basename "$f" .svg).png"
    BGCOLOR=`grep 'id="background"' $f \
        | sed 's/.* fill="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'`

    convert $f -transparent "$BGCOLOR" $g
done
```

Comment: Rube Goldberg would be proud.

Comment: I'm sorry @FredrickBrennan, I do not understand. 
Did you tried without the background rect on Imagick?

Comment: Yes, you only need `-background none` option to `convert`.