# GIMP script for converting EPS in other formats

Tags: gimp, eps

I use GIMP a lot on my linux machine to convert, modify and transform my pics especially EPS.
I was wondering if there is the possibility to automatically transform an EPS into another format or a generic pic format into EPS without importing/exporting manually?
Is there any possibility?

Thank you

Comment: 'cos I didn't know about that, I'm going to read something about it

Comment: @OcasoProtal you are a genius! Thank you so much. Now I have to figure out how to process all my images automatically!

Comment: Made my comment an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are on Linux, why don't you give [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#ps) a shot? Another option (depending on the complexity of your EPS) is [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.07/Use.htm#Options).

To convert your EPS to JPG you could use something like:

```
convert -density 300 image.eps -resize 1024x1024 image.jpg
```

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583821/how-to-convert-a-eps-file-to-a-high-quality-1024x1024-jpg) for more information.

EDIT:

Convert multiple files in the shell (untested, filenames must not contain space!):

```
for i in *.eps; do convert -density 300 ${i} ${i%eps}jpg; done
```

If you have filenames with spaces, you will have to use `find`.

Comment: I don't need to resize. Just to convert as it is. Thanks for the tip. Do you know how to process all the files without writing a bash script?

Comment: your automatic script works perfectly. Great. Thank you so much!